# foldr for a binary tree set

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

How can a foldr function be implemented for a set with signature:

```
(a -> b -> b) -> Set a -> b -> b
```

instead of

```
(a -> b -> b) -> b -> Set a -> b
```

where

`data Set x = Node | Tree x (Set x) (Set x)`

Comment: The same way as with the other signature, I guess?

Comment: To expand on @FyodorSoikin’s comment, you just need to change the order of the parameters. You almost certainly don’t even need to change the implementation of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the new function in terms of the original (note that this is not specific to `Set`; this works for any type constructor with a `Foldable` instance).

```
-- or any Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> t a -> b -> b
foldr' :: (a -> b -> b) -> Set a -> b -> b
foldr' f = flip (foldr f)
-- foldr' = flip . foldr
```

In other words, the new function is just `foldr` composed with `flip`.